# Original Xbox performance

Tags: xbox

So, I have been playing King Kong on the original Xbox and it runs both amazing and badly. If I’m in a cave or a small area, it runs smooth, but if it’s raining, or I’m in an open area or so on, it drops to like 10 frames a sec. Is it just because it’s an old console, is it a problem specific to the game, or is there something I can do to boost the performance?

Answer (score 2):

This has to do likely with the video chipset on the original XBOX. Like any machine, really, the amount of work that the GPU has to do goes up if there is more going on, on screen. When it is raining, there is alot of movement and pixels that have to be calculated and drawn. In an open area, there is far more clipping and 3D calculations going on. In a cave or some limited area, the amount of math involved is low.